# Scope gotcha when dynamically adding methods in a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have an API for analysing my exercise data (which I scrape [*runkeeper*](http://runkeeper.com/)'s website).

My main class is a subclass of a `pandas.DataFrame`, which is basically a container for tabular data. It supports indexing by column name, returning an array of the column values.

I would like to add some convenience properties based on the types of 'fitness activities' that are present in the data. So for example I'd like to add a property 'running':

```
@property
def running(self):
    return self[self['type'] == 'running']
```

Which would return all rows of the `DataFrame` which have 'running' in the 'type' column.

I tried to do this dynamically for all types present in the data. Here's what I naively did:

```
class Activities(pandas.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self,data):
        pandas.DataFrame.__init__(self,data)
        # The set of unique types in the 'type' column:
        types = set(self['type'])
        for type in types:
            method = property(lambda self: self[self['type'] == type])
            setattr(self.__class__,type,method)
```

The result was that all of these properties ended up returning tables of data for the same type of activity ('walking').

What's happening is that when the properties are accessed, the lambdas are called and they look in the scope they were defined in for the name 'type'. They find that it is bound to the string 'walking', since that was the last iteration of the for loop. Each iteration of the for loop doesn't have its own namespace, so all the lambdas see only the last iteration, rather than the value that 'type' had when they were actually defined.

Can anyone thing of a way around this? I can think of two, but they don't seem particularly ideal:

1. define `__getattr__` to check that the attribute is an activity type and return the appropriate rows.
2. use a recursive function call instead of a for loop, so that each level of recursion has its own namespace.

Both of these are a little too clever for my tastes, and `pandas.DataFrame` already has a `__getattr__` that I'd have to cautiously interact with if I made one too. And recursion would work, but feels very wrong since the set of types doesn't have any intrinsic tree-like structure to it. It's flat, and should look flat in the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the `lambda` to pull the values into the new scope.

```
method = property(lambda self=self, type=type: self[self['type'] == type])
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I need! However, if there are going to be multiple instances of this object around, the first argument to the lambda (self) probably shouldn't have a default set. This is because, as I just discovered, you have to add properties to the class rather than the instances (edited in my question). So we wouldn't want the property to point to a specific instance, otherwise the objects will return each other's data!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest *not* making a subclass of DataFrame, honestly, if you can avoid it. The old Java adage "favor composition over inheritance" tends to be preferable in my experience.

Comment: I'd almost always agree with you, but in this case the object I want is a `DataFrame` in every way, with the only difference being the addition of these methods.

So if I used composition instead, I'd be wrapping literally every `DataFrame` method. I guess when subclassing you often only want a subset of the parent class's features, in this case I really do want the whole lot.